# How to disable pydev debugger in visual studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pydev

I accidentally hit a suggestion from visual studio to run a preview debugger called *"pydev debugger"*. Now every time, I want to run a python code in the console it writes

```
pydev debugger: starting

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I want to disable it. I don't know how. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option under Tools, Options, Python, Debugging to "Use legacy debugger" (or depending on the version you have, it may be under Experimental still). Changing this option will restore the previous debugger.

However, since this appears to be undesirable behavior, you should also report it using the Report a Problem tool in Visual Studio. The team will likely want to know about it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem solved. As you mentioned, it was in the python, experimental, use experimental debugger in VS 2017.